# how to get value from string in form of key value pair

Tags: java

I get this value in String

```
kyc_CWaccountOperatorName|DANIYAL,kyc_cnic_ind|9110129505705,kyc_fatherName|Abujan,kyc_motherMaidenName|MOTHER,kyc_CWmobileNumber|03312551746,kyc_CWdateOfBirth|20/02/1993,kyc_cnicDateOfExpiry|2027-02-20,kyc_CWplaceOfBirth|KHI,kyc_mailAddHouseFlat No|Dha,kyc_city|Abbottabad
```

I want to get value of `kyc_cnic_ind` like
`kyc_cnic_ind=9110129505705`

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Share your tries or the question will closed for no efforts soon

Comment: I tried if(accHoldAttr.contains("kyc_cnic_ind")){} but I am confused how can I get value of this string

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What do you mean 'the value of the string' ? Surely it is 'kyc_cnic_ind'? But you already know that! Unless you want to extract the number after it,  9110129505705. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution for your problem:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str = new String("kyc_CWaccountOperatorName|DANIYAL,kyc_cnic_ind|9110129505705,kyc_fatherName|Abujan,kyc_motherMaidenName|MOTHER,kyc_CWmobileNumber|03312551746,kyc_CWdateOfBirth|20/02/1993,kyc_cnicDateOfExpiry|2027-02-20,kyc_CWplaceOfBirth|KHI,kyc_mailAddHouseFlat No|Dha,kyc_city|Abbottabad");
        String[] ar = str.replace("|","=").split(",",0);
        for(String s : ar)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

You can check output on the below link:

> https://ideone.com/kzBYfl

Comment: Great Job @Nishant Gupta